# Why is my change of basis incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem 6 part B from this [released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F08_Final_Exam-C.Zickert.pdf):

> Given an ordered basis of $W$, $\beta = \{ v_1, v_2 \}$ and $\beta' = \{v_1, v_1 + v_2 \}$ assume we have a ($T$-invariant) operator $T_W$ such that:
>   $$[T]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix} $$
>   Show that $$[T]_{\beta'} =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

My solution was to notice that:

$$Tv_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and:

$$Tv_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

So in the new basis the first column should be the same as we are just applying $T$ to $v_1$ again. In the second matrix we should do:

$$T(v_1 + v_2) = Tv_1 + Tv_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

And get:

$$ [T]_{\beta'} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

But instead it is:

$$ [T]_{\beta'} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where did my calculation go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[T]_{\beta^\prime}$ is the matrix representation of $T$ written in terms of the basis $\beta^\prime$. That is, you saw that $T(v_1 + v_2) = 2v_1 + v_2$, but that is really thinking about it *in terms of the basis $\beta$*.

Think about it this way: suppose $w_1 = v_1$ and $w_2 = v_1 + v_2$. Then, since $\{ w_1, w_2 \}$ is a basis, we can write $T(w_2)$ as $a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2$. Once you do that, then you'll see that $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 1$.